# Unnumbered foot notes with special characters

Tags: footnotes

I have a request to use a special character or symbol for a foot note.  Such as double 'S'.  Latex `\S` to see what I mean.  That is, instead of a number the symbol is used as a marker.  I've tried `\footnote[\S]{text of footnote}`, but LaTeX 'wants' a number within the square brackets `[]`.  Other special symbols could include a dagger or double dagger (`\dag` or `\ddag`), asterisk or others.

Any ideas?

Comment: In what context do you need those special footnotes? Is that for *all* footnotes? What kind of document are you writing?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `footmisc` package? It provides methods for (i) switching to symbolic footnote markers and (ii) selecting which symbols to use.

Comment: If you use `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` forces footnotes to use *nine* symbols included \S with `\footnote[4]{...}`. In this way each symbol has a number, namely: 1-`*`, 2-`\dag`, 3-`\ddag`, 4-`\S`, 5-`\P`, 6-`$\Vert$`, etc and you can use `\footnote[<n>]{...}` if you want to force a particular symbol, otherwise the footnotes will be numbered in that order.

Comment: A research paper with only one footnote.  skpblack's suggestion is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks 'black!

Comment: @skpblack: It may be easier to just use `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\S}` so that `\footnote{...}` works as expected (depending on your usage, of course, since there is a counter increment involved with a call to `\footenote`).

Comment: @skpblack -- Perhaps you could write an answer.